# ios firebase Auth with googleSignIn get IdToken for backend server

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I have developed a swift iOS app that implements Google SignIn using Firebase Auth, which works. I have a requirement to connect to a backend server which makes a google calendar API call and returns the last 10 events for the current signed in user. The back end server requires that i send the google idToken.

Will this firebase method return the google idtoken?

```
let currentUser = firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser
currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true, completion: handler)
```

or do i need to use this method?

```
accessToken = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser.authentication.accessToken
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a former member of the Firebase team, the third party tokens are separate from firebase tokens, and Google sign in tokens are considered third party oauth tokens.

In other words, you'd have to use `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser.authentication.accessToken` to get a Google token

Source: https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c

Comment: @ChrisMaley no problem. If this solves your problem, please accept my answer